# Call PowerShell Script from PowerShell Script with multiple arguments

Tags: powershell

I know, this has been asked a few times but I cannot seem to get it working. Basically, I am using multiple ps1 files so I don't have to have a very large script, in this case, its two files (so far):

**Migration-Main.ps1**

**Migration-Companies.ps1**

I want to call **Migration-Companies.ps1** from **Migration-Main.ps1** using invoke expression but this seems to only work if there is only one parameter in the target script, in my case there are two:

```
param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$false )]
    [datetime]$CompanyDateCull,  
    [parameter(mandatory=$false )]
    [string]$CompanyManagerCull
)

Write-Output $CompanyDateCull
```

So if I try to call the script like so:

```
Invoke-Expression "$Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull $CompanyDateCull -CompanyManagerCull "Fred""
```

I will get the following result:

```
Invoke-Expression : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Fred'.
At C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Scripts\Migrations\Imports\FastTrack-Migration-Main.ps1:282 char:1
+ Invoke-Expression "$Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull $CompanyDateCul ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

But if i remove the second parameter

```
Invoke-Expression "$Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull $CompanyDateCull"
```

it works:

```
Saturday, 21 September 2013 12:00:00 AM
```

I have tried running the file with other commands as well, such as simply calling PowerShell.exe:

```
PowerShell.exe -file $Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull $CompanyDateCull -CompanyManagerCull $CompanyManagerCull
```

But this stops any of my dot sourced functions from being accessible to the script being called, which is a requirement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use `Invoke-Expression` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first query you need escape the double quotes with backtick(`) :

```
Invoke-Expression "$Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull $CompanyDateCull -CompanyManagerCull `"Fred`""
```

Comment: Thankyou this works: Invoke-Expression "$Script_Companies -CompanyDateCull '$CompanyDateCull' -CompanyManagerCull '$CompanyManagerCull'"